# Scrollbars from ultragrid disappear when dock=filled

Tags: winforms, scrollbar, infragistics, dock, ultrawingrid

I'm writing a windows forms application with an ultragrid.

For layout reasons I'm using the dock property. When I put this property on none (from the ultragrid) the scrollbars are displayed.

When I put this property on fill the scrollbars are gone.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you mean horizontal scroll bar or vertical or both? Do you have enough records displayed to force the vertical one to appear? Do you have enough columns to force the horizontal one to display itself? What is the value of DisplayLayout.Scrollbars property?

Comment: Both. I've made enough records to force em to apper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer on the infragistics forum.
The problem was that other controls on the form where displayed in some way over the ultragrid (allthough it didn't look like it).
The solution is to **rightclick on the ultragrid in the form and then select 'bring to front'** . The next time i ran the application the scrollbars where there.